# HTML with &lt, &gt converting the latter to > but not the former

Tags: html, erlang

I'm trying to include < and > in a URL to reference an `erlang Pid`.

My output:

```
"You see only the darkness of the cavern.<br><a href=/choices/&lt0.223.0&gt>Venture cautiously.</a><br>"
```

I paste this into `foo.html` and open, I get a link to

file:///%22/choices/&lt0.207.0%3E/%22

notice the > came from the %3E but the &lt did not. Why did both HTML characters not stay as < and > ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark the end of an entity with a semicolon, for example `&lt;`.

Otherwise, it's ambiguous where the name ends. For `&gt>`, it is interpreted that the name is `gt`, because `>` is not a valid character for an entity name (it's not ASCII alphanumeric). However in `&lt0`, `0` is a valid character in an entity name. But `lt0` is not a defined entity. Supposedly there's some logic to find valid names in prefixes, but it would be nice to avoid relying on that altogether.

See here if you're interested in how exactly HTML entities are tokenized: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#character-reference-state